# Who can Empty Trash? (J4)

Tags: permissions

I have my own User Groups and have given one of them all rights to Articles. Users in that Group do not have access to the Empty Trash button. They can put things into Trash, but cannot empty it.
Can I change this? Seems like a shortfalling...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you may be aware, when you put things into the Trash you're just changing the state of the article, and to do this you require the Edit State permission. When you're emptying the Trash you're actually deleting the records and so require the Delete permission.

If you've given all the article permissions (including Delete) to the specific User Group then it's maybe the case that the individual user (or users) are also members of another user group which has been denied access to Delete (ie the Delete permission set to Denied rather than Inherited).

They could be members of another user group either through the admin directly assigning them to another group (edit the User and click on the Assigned User Groups tab) or because the user group is the child of another user group (click on Users / Groups to see the hierarchy).

When Joomla checks the permission it gets all the user groups that the user belongs to, and then gets all the parent user groups of those user groups. Then if any one of that combined set of user groups has got Denied against the Article Delete permission then it won't allow the user to empty the trash. The Denied takes priority - even if elsewhere they have Allowed.

You can see what permissions a user has by going in the back-end to Users / Manage to where it shows the list of users, and clicking on the Permissions button in the User Groups column. You can then check the permission against the Articles row, in the Delete column.

There are a couple of really good web resources explaining the Joomla ACL system - see [Joomla 3 ACL Explained video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFqXAc3orkY) (between 2 and 32 minutes is the section you want - and Joomla 4 is the same as Joomla 3 as far as I know), and also [Access Control List Tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial).

Best of luck! Joomla ACL is not for the faint-hearted!